# How to permanently unset an attribute of ArangoDB document?

Tags: arangodb

I want to remove an attribute from a document in ArangoDB.

I thought the correct method for this was with the function `UNSET(doc, attributeName1, ..., attributeNameN)`. However, with this alone, nothing is changed in the database.

Example:

```
let target_key = "42"

FOR doc IN myCollection
    FILTER doc._key == target_key
    RETURN UNSET(doc, "myAttribute")
```

The example returns the original document **without** the attribute `myAttribute`, but the new version is **not saved to the database**, so it seems this is only a projected copy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Alternatively, you can set the attribute you want to remove to `null` and use the `keepNull` option:

```
LET target_key = "42"

FOR doc IN myCollection
    FILTER doc._key == target_key
    UPDATE doc WITH { myAttribute: null } IN myCollection
    OPTIONS { keepNull: false }
    RETURN NEW
```

Attributes with an explicit `null` value in the document are kept. Only the attributes specified after WITH are touched.

Note: if you explain the query, you will see `nullMeansRemove: true` under *Write query options* instead of `keepNull: false`.

Comment: Hei, thanks for the input, I wasn't aware of this way. How does the `OPTIONS { keepNull: false }` treat other attributes with `null` in the document? Let's assume I want to remove an attribute but want to keep other attributes even if they are `null`. Another question is perhaps: what is the (dis)advantages of having no `null`-values?

Comment: As I mentioned, other attributes will remain unchanged, even if they are *null*. Only `myAttribute` will be removed by above query, because it is the only attribute provided: `WITH { myAttribute: null }`. In general, you may or may not store null values in your documents, it depends on what you need to express. In most cases, I assume you could simply remove an attribute if it is unused. If you need a distinction between a value being not available versus actually empty, it is legitimate to store a null value in the latter case.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks, I see now that you explicitly mentioned it. Which method do you think is better? Or, which answer do you think I should mark as "accepted answer"?

Comment: It doesn't really make a difference, a new document revision is written either way. `REPLACE` seems a bit more succinct. But if the attributes you want to remove are nested deeper, then `UPDATE MERGE_RECURSIVE(doc, { a: { b: { c: { targetKey: null } } } }) IN myCollection OPTIONS { keepNull: false }` is the way to go. I tried the same with `REPLACE`, but it doesn't support *keepNull*.

Answer (score 6):

The simple answer to this is to combine `UNSET` with the `REPLACE` function.

`UNSET` works on attributes in a single document, and `REPLACE` works on entire documents in a collection.

```
let target_key = "42"

FOR doc IN myCollection
    FILTER doc._key == target_key
    REPLACE UNSET(doc, "myAttribute") IN myCollection
    RETURN NEW
```

This example returns the new document where `myAttribute` is removed with `UNSET` that is saved to the collection with `REPLACE`.

The `NEW` and `OLD` keywords can be used as with `UPDATE` and `UPSERT`.

I figured this out after I read [this issue](https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues/1085). I felt this was a too simple task to get stuck on, but I hope this is of use to people after me.

Comment: *New* in *Return New* was not recognized, I removed the Return statement and worked just fine. Thanks for saving couple hours of my life.